# knockout simple binding issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

It could be one of the simplest forms of the knockout binding,

Couldn't find out what is the problem here :

**Fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/qfntcfn8/

```
            <input data-bind="text:newGroupName" type="text" />
            <button class="btn" type=button data-bind="click: addGroup()">
                Add Group
            </button>
```

**ViewModel :**

```
    var vm = $(function() {
        function baseViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.newGroupName = ko.observable();
            self.addGroup = function () {
                console.log(ko.toJSON(self.newGroupName)); // Expected newGroupName entered data
            };
        }
        var viewModel = new baseViewModel();
        ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("Box"));
    });
```

I expect to get newGroupName bound text as string after a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding input value, you need to use the `value` binding-handler:

```
<input data-bind="value: newGroupName" type="text" />
```

Also, since `newGroupName` is an observable *function*, you need to invoke it to get its value:

```
console.log(self.newGroupName())
```

Comment: correct, forgot that to bind to value, for a fast go, I copied from somewhere and there they bound to the text, SO didn't allow me to mark as the answer at first and I should be waited for 2 mins, thanks +1